# Overtightened tank bolts and caused cracks. What are my options?

Tags: toilet

In my case, the tank is intact, but the bolt hole in the base cracked off. The bowl itself is fully intact and water-tight. This is the bolt that holds the tank down to the base, not the bolt that holds the base down to the floor.

[image: Broken tank hold-down tab on toilet base]

Do I have any options other than replacement? I was considering epoxy, but I'm not sure how long something like that would last.

Comment: Is this for a toilet? If so replacing the fill valve and supply line would be the best choice. If on LP Gas bottles replacement is an absolute in my book.

Comment: @Bob, when you say "bolt hole in the base cracked off" do you mean that one of the mounting holes for bolting a toilet bowl to the flange/ring in the floor has broken? Can you post a picture on imgur.com and put a link to the pic in a comment on this post? We will then add the pic to your question.

Comment: Since you tagged this 'toilet', I'm gonna go with that. In theory, you could get longer bolts and use a big washer underneath, but on a risk (seriously flooded bathroom)/ reward (saved $150 on a toilet) basis, I'd vote for a new toilet.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyFix-it. I added a link to a couple of pictures on imgur. My description was not very clear!

Comment: With two-part-epoxy, your options again boil down to @AloysiusDefenestrate's comment above.

Comment: Given the picture, you can swap "big washer" for "chunk of plywood" in my comment. Could probably be done, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Time for a replacement